# Import Outlook contacts from a secondary email using Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I'm trying to open the Outlook contacts folder from a secondary email account.

This code will display the contacts on my default email account.

I tried `.Session.Accounts`. Is there a way I can open a folder from the path? If so, how would I get the path for contacts folder?

```vb
Private Sub Command12_Click()
Dim xOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim xNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim xFolder As Outlook.Folder
        
'
'On Error Resume Next
Set xOutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set xNameSpace = xOutlookApp.Session
Set xFolder = xNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(10)
xFolder.Display
'
Set xFolder = Nothing
Set xNameSpace = Nothing
Set xOutlookApp = Nothing
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, call `Store.GetDefaultFolder`. A `Store` object can be retrieved from the `Namespace.Stores` collection.